# Should we have temporary moderators who can help vote to close off topic answers?

Tags: discussion, moderators, vote-to-close, private-beta

Would it be useful if some people who participated in the private beta were made moderators - at least until the end of the public beta - so that we (as a group) can keep on top of the off topic questions that are bound to be asked?

Prompted by [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/what-is-the-best-pdf-organizer-on-local-desktop) and [now this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/ripping-cds-to-mp3-format-using-itunes).

Comment: I would suggest that people that are moderator (or have over 10k rep) on an other stack exchange site have access to moderation tool during the beta phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deployed a change to relax the rep requirements this, and all future, public betas.

They were already relaxed (severely) for private beta.

See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation for the exact numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I know on the Trilogy sites users need to have over 10k rep to vote to close questions but maybe there should be a lower cap on new StackExchange sites that have less users and less rep.  Maybe based off of some steps or a a % until enough people hit 10k rep.

For example, right now on WebApps, the highest Rep user is still under 1500 rep.  That means if we assume a flat rate of growth (probably not accurate), it will be another 40 days before even 1 user hits 10k rep.  Couldn't there be some system like this:

1. Under 250 questions - You need 500 Rep to vote to close
2. Under 500 questions - You need 1000 Rep to vote to close
3. Under 1000 questions - You need 5000 Rep to vote to close
4. Over 2000 questions - You need 10,000 Rep to vote to close
   *Note I don't know the Rep levels per number of questions and votes in existence so this would just be a guess.

I know it would make things more complex and maybe it has been discussed elsewhere but for new site this is going to be a common issue until it gets solved.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the numbers would need tweaking. We're already at over 600 questions and no one has anywhere near 5,000 rep.

Comment: Why is the gap so big between #2 and #3 ? 2 times more question, but 5 times more Rep required ...

Comment: You only need 3k rep on the Trilogy sites to be able to vote to close.